# Vue-Select event trigger without Node.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am using Vue.js and Vue-Select without node.js. I am importing them directly into my html file like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
```

I have a v-select menu defined in `<body>` with an on-change option which should call `hello()`

```
<v-select on-change="hello" :options="['foo','bar','baz', 'asdf']"></v-select>
```

And the Vue-Select component is registered like this, with the `hello()` method;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

        new Vue({
          el: 'body',
          methods: {
            hello (val) {
              alert(val)
            }
          }
        });

</script>
```

But alas nothing happens and I get the following error message in console:

```
vue.js:990 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for onChange="hello". Expected Function, got String.
```

This is based on the `on-change callback` event described in the vue-select [documentation](http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/)... but it doesn't work.

I would just like to to create an event when the select box is changed; i.e. I would like pass the value of the select box to a function which does something.

Comment: What is the error you get, how are you using it, add that code.

Comment: i have updated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is in your template, you need to bind the `on-change` property otherwise it's just sending a string to the instance.

```
<v-select v-on:on-change="hello" :options="['foo','bar','baz', 'asdf']"></v-select>
```

or if you prefer shorthand.

```
<v-select @on-change="hello" :options="['foo','bar','baz', 'asdf']"></v-select>
```

EDIT:

Ok I'm a bit of a moron not noticing the binding method you need to use `v-bind` or the `:` shorthand as seen here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vok1ggoc/2/) looking at the v-select code on github I noticed they're explicitly calling the function instead of emitting it.

so your html should be

```
<v-select v-bind:on-change="hello" :options="['foo','bar','baz', 'asdf']"></v-select>
<v-select :on-change="hello" :options="['foo','bar','baz', 'asdf']"></v-select>
```

Comment: That should not be an issue, that's how it is in the [documentation](http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/) as well.

Comment: @Saurabh I've yet to see a case where that works the way it shows in that documentation, in the Vuejs.org [Event Handling](http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) Docs it specifies the need for `v-on` or the `@` shorthand when passing functions or expressions to a callback. As well if you notice the vue-warn @eli gives us is that it was expecting a function and received a string.

Comment: I tried making some fiddles to test with [Question](https://jsfiddle.net/vok1ggoc/) gives the vue-warn [Our Answers](https://jsfiddle.net/vok1ggoc/1/) don't yet the function isn't called. Which is an oddity

Answer (score 0):

As there is a validation in the [code](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/blob/master/src/components/Select.vue#L350), for onchange to be a function, You should try one with function syntax, like following:

```
  Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

    new Vue({
      el: 'body',
      methods: {
        hello: function(val) {
          alert(val)
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this but still get the same error (vue.js:990 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for onChange="hello". Expected Function, got String.)

Comment: @eli I am not sure you can do `el: 'body`, you have to give that div an id, and use that id here, that might tne the issue.

Comment: el:body works (the select box is shown) and it's done that way in the vue.js documentation. using a div made no difference